# How can I use User/Pass authentication method for a third party service with Data Studio Community Connectors?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, looker-studio, google-apps-script-api

I'm trying to create a connector that fetch data from an API. The API authentication need username and password and return a token in the end.
For now  I'm using TextInput element of the getConfig() methode to get username and password from the user.

**What I want to do :**
Display an HTML page to the user which contain username and password input. ***directly*** after Data Studio authorization. How can I do that with app script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `USER_PASS` authentication method. This will generate the credentials input screen for you and you do not need to create your own HTML page. See the [Authentication guide](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/auth#user_pass) for example code for implementation.